# A question regarding "in the back of"

Tags: prepositions, phrases

What does "in the back of" mean? Does it have the same meaning as "at the back of" which is opposite to "in/at the front of"?
Can I say "John sits in the back of the classroom"? If so, I am wondering whether "in the back of" is British English and "at the back of" is American English. Am I right?

Reference website:http://learn2speakenglishonline.blogspot.com/2010/11/preposition-differences-britishamerican.html

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/pzp2ljj  The info may have been true for AmE in the first quarter of the 20th c, but since WWII, they have reached parity.

Comment: Unfortunately, that graph is useless at best.

Answer (score 1):

In the back of/at the back of

Yes, they are opposite to the phrases in the front of/at the front of. According to Ngram Review provided  by TRomano, both are almost equally used in AE. However, in BE, the use of the latter is more usual.